# How can I change `level distance` for a specific subtree of a tikz-qtree?

Tags: tikz-qtree

E.g., in the following example, I wish to set `level distance=32pt` just for the PP subtree.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz, tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree [.S [.NP [.Det the ] [.N cat ] ]
[.VP [.V sat ]
[.PP [.P on ]
[.NP [.Det the ] [.N mat ] ] ] ] ]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I'd expect `[.\node[level distance=32pt]{PP}; [.P on ]` to work, but it doesn't.

Comment: I don't think there's a simple way to do this with `tikz-qtree` other than the solution that Simon gives. And unless you have a lot invested in `tikz-qtree` already, you may want to consider switching to `forest` instead. Unrelated, but it's linguistically incorrect to have lines between terminal node labels and their contents, so you should add `[anchor=north,align=center]` to your global options, and then use e.g. `[.Det\\the ]` rather than `[.Det the ]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here there are two connected subtrees. The first with `level distance=30pt`  and the second, starting in `PP` with `level distance=60pt`

(This is how I interpreted your question)

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz, tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikzset{level distance=30pt}
        \Tree [.S [.NP [.Det the ] [.N cat ] ]
        [.\node(e3){VP}; [.V sat ]]]
    \begin{scope}[shift={(60pt,-60pt)}]
        \tikzset{level distance=60pt}
        \Tree [.\node(e4){PP}; [.P on ]
        [.NP [.Det the ] [.N mat ] ]]
    \end{scope}
    \draw (e3.south)--(e4); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Or**

[image: b]

Using

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikzset{level distance=30pt}
        \Tree [.S [.NP [.Det the ] [.N cat ] ]
        [.\node(e3){VP}; [.V sat ]]]
    \begin{scope}[shift={(60pt,-90pt)}]
        \tikzset{level distance=30pt}
        \Tree [.\node(e4){PP}; [.P on ]
        [.NP [.Det the ] [.N mat ] ]]
    \end{scope}
    \draw (e3.south)--(e4); 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to TeX.SE!

Do you after following?

[image]

This is easy to obtain by use of `forest` package:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree = {text depth=3pt, 
            inner sep=0pt,
            anchor=north
            }
[S
    [NP 
        [Det[the ]]
        [N  [cat ]]
    ] 
    [VP 
        [V  
            [sat , tier=L]
        ]
        [PP, fit=band, tier=L
            [P [on ]]
            [NP [Det [the ] ]
                [N   [mat ] ]
            ]
        ]
    ] 
]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```